# Mac login via server

Tags: macos, mac, synology, ldap

For my small business I have bought a Mac mini. Soon an extra employee will start to work here and he will use that Mac mini.

I can create 2 accounts on the Mac Mini, my own admin account and another user account for him, but with the future in mind I would like to do it more futureproof.

My goal is to create some sort of server on my Synology where I can add one or more accounts. On this Mac (or another one in the future) every single account can login and has his / her own files / settings.

I installed Synology LDAP package and I can connect to it on my Mac. When I try to login with one of the created accounts in the LDAP server, the Mac starts to show the loader to open the desktop but keeps doing that (for over an hour).

When I enter "wrong" credentials it shows that the credentials are incorrect, which means the Mac is successfully connected to the LDAP server.

What did I do wrong, or is this the right way to set this up?

It would be nice if the files where stored on the Synology and every account on the mac can just use my (admin account) installed programs

Or is there a way i can configurate a whole mac environment somewhere without installing apps on every single Mac?

I'm sorry if my question is unclear but I am not sure how to ask this properly

Comment: Any user can use any & all apps installed in the main /Applications directory. Apps inside the user's own home directory ~/Applications can only be used by that user. I'm not sure why you think you need LDAP for any of this. You need to tell us what it is you are actually trying to achieve, don't start from how you think you will achieve it. That's an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Comment: My goal is to have for example 5 macs (in the future), and all 5 employees can login into any of those macs and have their personal settings / files. The 5 employee login credentials should be saved on some server so i can manage them at one place instead of on every Mac

Comment: OK, that wasn't really apparent from your question. Sorry, that's way outside my experience. Have you seen https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/directory-utility/diru566b498a/mac

Comment: Thank you anyway. I saw that and i followed all the steps, It seems to work except that the login seems to freeze

Comment: Is there a way i can see the log realtime via SSH (on another computer) and then try to login again. The mac will freeze again but maybe i can see log values?